# How to set database session parameter as application logged in user in .Net

Tags: .net, oracle

My web application is developed in Dot NET.
I want to set database session parameter as application logged in user (say 'user1').

I can perform below steps:

1. create and open new database connection

   ```
   dbConn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cdbadb"].ConnectionString.ToString());
   ```
2. set session parameter

   ```
   EXEC DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('user1');
   ```
3. execute database query
4. close connection

I am assuming that creating mew db connection creates a new DB session.
Please correct me if i am wrong.

Also, in case of db pooling by dot net framework, how to ensure that connection used by current user has db session parameter correctly set?

I want to get rid of setting session parameter before executing each query.
Please advice.

P. S. : I am implementing Oracle row level security for non database users using `DBMS_RLS`

Comment: Can you show the configuration part, which sets the parameters about session in your application?

Comment: Do you need code showing how i am executing "EXEC DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('user1');" Please clarify what configuration you need